# image appears faded out if the browser lt ie10

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, fancybox

I'm developing a gallery and it works fine in Chrome/Firefox/IE11/IE10, but there is an issue with IE9/IE8.

I'm using fancybox to display the gallery, and when the gallery open, the image appears with an effect like if the images take an opacity:0.1, the following screenshot shows what I'm meaning..

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASt7i.jpg)

If the browser is less than Ie10 I give the HTML this class `lt-ie10`

---

**CSS code**

```
html:not(.lt-ie10) .fancybox-image { 
   z-index:1;   
   -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity:0;
   -moz-opacity:0; 
} 

.ie_gallery .fancybox-image , .lt-ie10 .fancybox-image {  
   z-index:1;
   -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=1)" !important;
   filter: alpha(opacity=1) !important;
   opacity:1 !important;
   -moz-opacity:1 !important; 
}
```

---

**JS code**

```
    $('.product-image a.fancybox').fancybox({
        closeEffect: 'fade',
        afterLoad : function() {
            $("#product .product-image img").addClass('fancylarge');
            if($('ul.mycarousel li').length > 1) $('.fancybox-inner').before('<i class="arrow_right fancy arrow"></i>').before('<i class="arrow_left fancy arrow"></i>');
            $('<div class="loading"></div>').clone().appendTo($('.fancybox-skin'));
            var ie = false;
            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/trident/i) ) ie=true;
            if(!ie){
                $(".fancybox-inner").load('null',null,function(){$(".fancybox-image").css('top',($('.fancybox-inner').height()-$(".fancybox-image").height())/2).animate({opacity:1});});
            }else{
                $('body').addClass('ie_gallery');
            }
        },
        beforeClose: function() {
            $("#product .product-image img").removeClass('fancylarge');
            $('.fancybox-skin .mycarousel-hide').remove();
            $('.fancybox-skin .mycarousel-hide').removeClass('large_width');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

IE opacity filters use a 0-100 range rather than a 0-1 range, so you're filters for the opaque style should be like this:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
```

Currently they are being set to 1% opacity, which makes them appear to be totally gone.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its a bad mistake :(